# How to scroll the content view based on content size in Ios using autolayouts

Tags: ios, swift

layouts and in my project i have added scrollview on view controller using auto-layouts and i have added one content view on this scrollview

so for everything is ok but i want scroll the the content view based on content size  and  for this i have searched lot but i did not get result please help me

According to my code screen is displays like below i'e remaining data is not scrolling what did i do here wrong(here this scroll must  matching in all i-phone and i-pad inches)

### my code:-

```
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface ViewController3 ()
{
    UIScrollView * scrollView;
    UIView * containerView;
    UITextView * TextView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController3


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    //Applying autolayouts for scrollview
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint1];

    TextView = [UITextView new];
    TextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    TextView.text = @"In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]In December 2012, Tendulkar announced his retirement from ODIs.[23] He retired from Twenty20 cricket in October 2013[24] and subsequently announced his retirement from all forms of cricket,[25][26] retiring on 16 November 2013 after playing his 200th and final Test match, against the West Indies in Mumbai's Wankhede Stadium.[27] Tendulkar played 664 international cricket matches in total, scoring 34,357 runs.[8]";
    TextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [containerView addSubview:TextView];

    //Applying autolayouts for textview1
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:20.0f];
    [containerView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f];
    [containerView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f];
    [containerView addConstraint:constraint];

    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:600];
    [containerView addConstraint:constraint];

    //Applying autolayouts for containerview
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:-10.0f];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];

    constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [scrollView addConstraint:constraint2];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
UIScrollView * scroll = ...
[self.view addSubview: scroll];

UIView * scrollWrapper = ... 
[scroll addSubview: scrollWrapper];

// each new view will be added as a subview of "scrollWrapper"

UIView *mainView = self.view;

NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scroll, scrollWrapper, mainView);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scroll]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scroll]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

[scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollWrapper]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];
[scroll addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollWrapper]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];

/* add constraints for subviews */
[scrollWrapper addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"<VFL Constraint>" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary]];


/* this is the key to make the content scrollable */
[mainView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[scrollWrapper(==mainView)]" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: i ma too much confusing please explain clearly because i am new for auto-layouts and if you dont' mind please modified my code and post that

Comment: this is not suitable to my requirement

Comment: Replace your viewDidLoad method with the one I provided in this URL:
https://github.com/narcistabarasi/iOS_examples/blob/master/scrollview_autolayout/DEMOViewController.m

Comment: I am using VFL to define the constraints in the example above. Check this link for more info on VFL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Comment: ok thanks can you give me the same solution in constrainh with item formate please?